# Cambiar el estilo a la paginación

Tags: c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Bueno quería cambiar el estilo del diseño de la página que creé con PagedListMvc y PagedList en c# porque antes el diseño de la página se veía bien pero agregué la plantilla y la cambió y no se ve igual que antes y me gustaría cambiar el estilo para que se vea mejor.

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, pageSize = ViewBag.PageSize }))

[![Antes se veia asi][1]][1]

[![nY ahora se ve asi ][2]][2]

Alguien que me pueda ayudar

Comment: Si tu intención era añadir imágenes, no se ven